# MVC Model State Validation fails on Listbox

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a simple model which uses a multi select listbox for a many-many EF relationship.

On my `Create` action, I'm getting the error

> The parameter conversion from type 'System.String' to type 'MyProject.Models.Location' failed because no type converter can convert between these types.

I have 2 models, an Article and a Location:

Article.cs

```
namespace MyProject.Models
{
    public class Article
    {
        public Article()
        {
            Locations = new List<Location>();
        }

        [Key]
        public int ArticleID { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Article Title is required.")]
        [MaxLength(200, ErrorMessage = "Article Title cannot be longer than 200 characters.")]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Location> Locations { get; set; }
    }
```

Location.cs:

```
namespace MyProject.Models
{
    public class Location
    {
        [Key]
        public int LocationID { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Location Name is required.")]
        [MaxLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Location Name cannot be longer than 100 characters.")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Article> Articles { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I have a ViewModel:

```
namespace MyProject.ViewModels
{
    public class ArticleFormViewModel
    {
        public Article article { get; set; }
        public virtual List<Location> Locations { get; set; }

        public ArticleFormViewModel(Article _article, List<Location> _locations)
        {
            article = _article;
            Locations = _locations;
        }
    }
}
```

create.cshtml:

```
@model MyProject.ViewModels.ArticleFormViewModel
<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Article</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.article.Title)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.article.Title)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.article.Title)
        </div>
        <h3>Locations</h3>
        @Html.ListBoxFor(m=>m.article.Locations,new MultiSelectList(Model.Locations,"LocationID","Name"))
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

Finally my controller actions:

```
// GET: /Article/Create

public ActionResult Create()
{

    var article = new Article();
    var AllLocations = from l in db.Locations
                      select l;

    ArticleFormViewModel viewModel = new ArticleFormViewModel(article, AllLocations.ToList());

    return View(viewModel);


}

//
// POST: /Article/Create

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(Article article)
{
    var errors = ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors);

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var locations = Request.Form["article.Locations"];
        if (locations != null)
        {
            var locationIDs = locations.Split(',');
            foreach (var locationID in locationIDs)
            {
                int id = int.Parse(locationID);
                Location location = db.Locations.Where(l => l.LocationID == id).First();
                article.Locations.Add(location);
            }
        }

        db.Articles.Add(article);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    var AllLocations = from l in db.Locations
                       select l;
    ArticleFormViewModel viewModel = new ArticleFormViewModel(article, AllLocations.ToList());
    return View(viewModel);

}
```

This all works relatively well, my Locations listbox is populated properly:

[image]

If I do not select a Location then my model is saved properly.  If I select one or more locations then my Model.IsValid check fails with the exception

> The parameter conversion from type 'System.String' to type 'MyProject.Models.Location' failed because no type converter can convert between these types.

However if I remove the ModelState.IsValid check then despite the error my values are all correctly saved into the database - just that I lose validation for things such as the model title.

Hope someone can help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you create a type converter, you cannot directly bind the results of your list box directly to a complex object like that.  The reason lies in the fact that MVC can only deal with posted HTTP values, which in this case are an array of strings that contain the selected ID's.  Those strings do not directly map to your Locations object (ie the number 1 cannot be directly converted to a Locations object with an ID of 1).

Your best bet is to have a list of location ID's in your View Model of type string or int to accept the posted values, then in your post method create the Location objects and fill them with the correct ID's.

FYI, the reason your code works is because you are bypassing the model binding and going directly to the Request.Form collection.  You will notice that the bound Article object will not have any Location objects.

EDIT:

I don't even see how your code would work even without this problem.  Your ArticleFormViewModel does not have a parameterless constructor, so that will fail in model binding (unless you have a custom model binder).

In any event, what you want to do is this (note, you will have to populate SelectedLocationIDs if you want them to be selected when the view is rendered):

```
public class ArticleFormViewModel
{
    ...
    List<int> SelectedLocationIDs { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Then, in your view you have:

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(m=>m.SelectedLocationIDs, 
    new MultiSelectList(Model.Locations,"LocationID","Name"))
```

In your Post method, instead of the code that calls Request.Form, you have something like this:

```
foreach(var locationID in article.SelectedLocationIDs) {
    ... // look up your locations and add them to the model
}
```

Comment: Ok that makes a lot of sense, and I didn't realise that Request.Form bypassed the model binding.  I'm struggling to adapt your comment to my code though, are you able to show me how I would change the code?

Comment: Perfect, helped me out immensely.