# MVC 5 dropdownlist model state false conversion from type 'System.String' to type 'Namespace.Models.Entity'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, html.dropdownlistfor, modelbinders

Im very new to MVC and am starting to understand and develop a RL (simple) application, however im stuck at creating a record,I can't seem to be able to post my form contents because of this error :

> "the parameter conversion from type 'System.String' to type
>   'Namespace.Models.Entity'because no converter can make this conversion"

on one of my fields, however, there is another field with a dropdownlist too that does work correctly, maybe is it because one of those fields is a navigation relationship in the model?
The model is for a Questionnare Application
 and here is the main Question model: 
(generated with EF database First)

```
    public partial class QuestionContent
{
    public QuestionContent()
    {
        this.QuestionTranslations = new HashSet<QuestionTranslations>();
        this.QuestionMedicalCategory = new HashSet<QuestionMedicalCategory>();
        this.QuestionCategory = new HashSet<QuestionCategory>();
        this.QuestionContent1 = new HashSet<QuestionContent>();
    }

    public int QItemId { get; set; }
    public string Language { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> ParentQId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<QuestionTranslations> QuestionTranslations {       get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<QuestionMedicalCategory>      QuestionMedicalCategory { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<QuestionCategory> QuestionCategory { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<QuestionContent> QuestionContent1 { get; set; }
    public virtual QuestionContent QuestionContent2 { get; set; }
}
```

The category model is this one :

```
namespace AskusOnlinePrototype.Models{
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public partial class QuestionCategory
{
    public QuestionCategory()
    {
        this.QuestionContent = new HashSet<QuestionContent>();
    }

    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string CategoryDescription { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<QuestionContent> QuestionContent { get; set; }
}}
```

My "Create" Controller (I copied the dropdownList implementation seeing the ParentQId Viewbag SelectList that does not generate any errors in modelstate)

```
public ActionResult Create()
    {

        ViewBag.QuestionCategory = new SelectList(db.QuestionCategory, "CategoryId", "CategoryDescription");
ViewBag.ParentQId = new SelectList(db.QuestionContent, "QItemId", "Content");//Generated by VS
        ViewBag.DefaultLanguage = "EN";
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Language,Content,ParentQId,QuestionMedicalCategory,QuestionCategory")] QuestionContent questionContent)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.QuestionContent.Add(questionContent);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
        }
        catch (DataException /* dex */)
        {

            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save changes. Try again, and if the problem persists see your system administrator.");
        }

        ViewBag.QuestionCategory = new SelectList(db.QuestionCategory, "CategoryId", "CategoryDescription");
        ViewBag.ParentQId = new SelectList(db.QuestionContent, "QItemId", "Content");

            ViewBag.DefaultLanguage = "EN";
            return View(questionContent);



    }
```

And My Create View (Simplified to show the problem)

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

     @Html.LabelFor(model => model.QuestionCategory,"Item Category") 

@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.QuestionCategory,null, "Select Category")


//This DropDownListFor implementation does not generate errors in modelstate        
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.ParentQId, "Select Parent ")

            @Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.ParentQId, null," -- None --")


        </div>
    </div>
```

I've researched several Questions in SO and have been addressing the problem for a few days by now but I give up because most of them deal with much more complex models, or multiSelectLists, I mean, this should be simple! my question is, I know the DefaultModelBinder sees these fields (as medicalCategory gives me the same problem but i think addressing this one will fix medicalCategory too, because in model state it shows that the "intended value" is for example '1' in a given chosen Questioncategory, so, Is there something I should do when that DropDownLists binds to a navigation relationship, is there the need to modify the modelbinder? if so, could you please help me to where to start to understand how form post works with these kind of views? the most similar question to mine I've found is [[MVC Model State Validation fails on Listbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16138450/mvc-model-state-validation-fails-on-listbox][1]) but the answer seems too stretched for my simple model, nevertheless, if you think its the correct answer, please point me so.

Thanks and if you dont know the answer but have an idea of what should I research Id appreciate it too!

Comment: I encountered a similar error due to using a `reserve word`. So, if the problem is caused from a similar issue, you might have a look at my answer on [The parameter conversion from type 'System.String' to type 'T' failed because no type converter can convert between these types](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6406094/the-parameter-conversion-from-type-system-string-to-type-t-failed-because-no/35025214#35025214). Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

I believe the other question you referenced is spot on. You need to either build the converter for your complex type or do something like this

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.QuestionCategory.CategoryId,null, "Select Category")
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, I'll try both  and post the results

Answer (score -1):

To anyone who might ever stumble upon this question, It seems the problem, as noted above corresponding to a similar question, comes from the fact that the Select item in a SelectList contains an array of values that in most cases can't be converted to a complex type as it is in the model, in my case an Icollection to another model. This is of my undestanding of the nature of the exception and the model and the binding of the values submitted, in which case, there needs to be created a type converter, nevertheless in some cases, I found that it is more recommended to build a custom model binder, because the values in the SelectList don't even point to values in the model, they come from the viewbag List.
 In my case I made a custom model binder in which I used those values with a foreach, adding them to the Icollection<>, If you need some help getting started with a custom model binder I leave you this link [Creating a Custom Model Binder in MVC](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/605595/ASP-NET-MVC-Custom-Model-Binder)